# Python: printing out contents of a dictionary horizontal with a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I would like to print out the keys of a dictionary horizontal and on every third key to make a new line. I wrote this like that:

```
fields= {1 : "not", 2 : "not", 3 : "not",
         4 : "not", 5 : "not", 6 : "not",
         7 : "not", 8 : "not", 9 : "not"} 
for i in fields:
print(i)
if i%3==0:
    print ("\n")
```

However, the output is then just horizontal with two newlines between every third number.

The ouput I would like to have is this:

> 123
>
> 456
>
> 789

Comment: Your question assumes the dict is ordered, which is not true here.

Comment: So ordering a dict will fix this? Cause I noticed that when printing out a string this way will lead to the same vertical output

Comment: Which version of Python are you using, 
print(i) should print one per line, add a comma at the end to print on the same line, with a space added. 

change 
print(i)
to
print(i),

; other than that, yes, the ordering is not guaranteed (but doesn't solve your issue)

; On a deeper level, "WHAT ARE YOU TRYING TO DO? " 

Why do you need the keys printed this way? do the coordinates matter? is this the right data structure to hold that info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
fields= {1 : "not", 2 : "not", 3 : "not",
         4 : "not", 5 : "not", 6 : "not",
         7 : "not", 8 : "not", 9 : "not"}
for Key,values in fields.items():
    print(Key, end = "")#python3 , if in python2 use print item, instead.
    if Key%3==0:
        print ("\n")


123

456

789
```

Comment: Glad to help ~ Just base on your effort and change a little bit ~

Answer (score 0):

If you use python 3, or import the print function for python 2, you can specify the end parameter of print, like this: `print(i, end="")`, and there won't be a newline between the dictionary keys.
But as dictionary keys are not ordered, they will be printed in a "random" order, to avoid this, make a list of the keys, and sort it before printing, like this: `keys = sorted(dict.keys())`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `sys.stdout.write()` instead of print, which will not append any ending to its parameter, but it only accepts string objects

Answer (score 0):

`print (i),` will do the trick for you. On a side note, the indentation of your code is not correct.

```
fields= {1 : "not", 2 : "not", 3 : "not",
         4 : "not", 5 : "not", 6 : "not",
         7 : "not", 8 : "not", 9 : "not"} 
for i in fields:
  print (i),
  if i%3==0:
    print ("\n")`
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the solutions work for the given case, I would like to explain something to you. 
`dictionary` in python is not ordered. In this case it is fine because of the way you declared it with just simple `1,2,3...` keys. You might **think** that's how dict work. **NO**!

```
>>> a = {1 : "not", 2 : "not", 3 : "not",4 : "not", 5 : "not", 6 : "not",7 : "not", 8 : "not", 9 : "not"}
>>> a
{1: 'not', 2: 'not', 3: 'not', 4: 'not', 5: 'not', 6: 'not', 7: 'not', 8: 'not', 9: 'not'}
```

Good right so in this case all the solutions would work. However if you think the same and try the same code for the following `dict`

```
>>> a= {12 : "not", 21 : "not", 30 : "not",4 : "not", 15 : "not", 61 : "not",71 : "not", 8 : "not", 19 : "not"}
```

The output would be **not** in the same order.

```
>>> a
{19: 'not', 4: 'not', 21: 'not', 71: 'not', 8: 'not', 12: 'not', 61: 'not', 30: 'not', 15: 'not'}
```

And if you try to iterate and print using `for keys in a:` you would run into many problems.

So you want the desired output (dict is not ordered so unpredictable) use `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict
fields = [(1, 'not'), (2, 'not'), (3, 'not'),
          (4, 'not'), (5, 'not'), (6, 'not'),
          (7, 'not'), (8, 'not'), (9, 'not')]
a = OrderedDict(fields)
for i,key in enumerate(a):
    print(key,end='')
    i+=1
    if i%3==0:
        print()
```

output:

```
123
456
789
```

Also `enumerate()` should be used to print every three values. Don't rely on the key. What if you key changes?

i,key of enumerate(dictionary) just gives out values like these `0,key1`,`1,key2`,`2,key3`,...and so on. Just gives out pairs of number,item that's all.

Try changing the keys and use this code and other codes and you'll notice how much you change the results will be same for this solution. And not for the others. **Remember** always your code should be adaptable. Shouldn't entirely depend on only specific sets of input

```
123
456
789
```

Also **Note** just `print()` would do if you want them separated into newlines. use `print("\n") if you want a gap (newline) between them.

```
123

456

789
```